# SWIG and Java: how to map a c++ pointer to pointer to object output parameter to Java

Tags: java, c++, swig

*First of all, I found several matching questions, but found no satisfying answer. Most of them cover pointer-to-pointer c arguments (and not c++). And some of the cover Python instead of Java.*

I have a c++ method which has an output parameter which is a pointer to a pointer to an object. I want to call this method from Java.

In the documentation for using SWIG with Java, I found [this Butler example](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#struct_pointer_pointer). It's almost what I need, except that it covers structs instead of objects. It is also written for C instead of C++. I started from this example, figuring that what I need would probably look a lot like this example (maybe I need a completely different approach, but I gave it a try anyway).

The original C implementation looks like this:

```
int HireButler(Butler **ppButler) {
  Butler *pButler = (Butler *)malloc(sizeof(Butler));
  pButler->hoursAvailable = 24;
  pButler->greeting = (char *)malloc(32);
  strcpy(pButler->greeting, "At your service Sir");
  *ppButler = pButler;
  return 1;
}
```

In my C++ version, it looks like this (I made the HireButler and FireButler static methods of the Butler class):

```
class Butler {
    // ... necessary class members, getters and setters go here ...

    static int HireButler(Butler **ppButler) {
      Butler *pButler = new Butler();
      pButler->setHoursAvailable(24);
      pButler->setGreeting("At your service Sir");
      *ppButler = pButler;
      return 1;
    }

    static void FireButler(Butler *pButler) {
      delete pButler;
    }
};
```

For the SWIG interfance file, I almost completely copied the code from the example. Except I had to change the c-style JNI calls to c++-style JNI calls (so that's jenv-> instead of (*jenv)-> and drop the first argument):

```
// Do not generate the default proxy constructor or destructor
%nodefaultctor Butler;
%nodefaultdtor Butler;

// Add in pure Java code proxy constructor
%typemap(javacode) Butler %{
  /** This constructor creates the proxy which initially does not create nor own any C memory */
  public Butler() {
    this(0, false);
  }
%}

// Type typemaps for marshalling Butler **
%typemap(jni) Butler ** "jobject"
%typemap(jtype) Butler ** "Butler"
%typemap(jstype) Butler ** "Butler"

// Typemaps for Butler ** as a parameter output type
%typemap(in) Butler ** (Butler *ppButler = 0) %{
  $1 = &ppButler;
%}
%typemap(argout) Butler ** {
  // Give Java proxy the C++ pointer (of newly created object)
  jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass("Butler");
  jfieldID fid = jenv->GetFieldID(clazz, "swigCPtr", "J");
  jlong cPtr = 0;
  *(Butler **)&cPtr = *$1;
  jenv->SetLongField($input, fid, cPtr);
}
%typemap(javain) Butler ** "$javainput"
```

After I generate the necessary Java and C++ wrapper code using SWIG, everything compiles and the Java code looks good. However, when I try to run the following Java code, I get an exception:

```
    Butler jeeves = new Butler();
    Butler.HireButler(jeeves);
    System.out.println("Greeting:     " + jeeves.getGreeting());
    System.out.println("Availability: " + jeeves.getHoursAvailable() + " hours per day");
```

From the bug report file, the exception seems to happen when retrieving the swigCPtr field using JNI:

```
Stack: [0x0000000002590000,0x0000000002690000],  sp=0x000000000268f630,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x136519]
C  [TestDll.dll+0x411f]  JNIEnv_::GetFieldID+0x4f
C  [TestDll.dll+0x4e05]  Java_com_test_exampleJNI_Butler_1HireButler+0x95
C  0x000000000297dcec
```

Unfortunately, I have absolutely no experience with JNI, so I am now pretty stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is typical, right after I asked my question I got my aha-moment and found what the issue is.

I need to use a fully-qualified class name in the JNI call:

```
jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass("com/test/Butler");
```

instead of

```
jclass clazz = jenv->FindClass("Butler");
```